# Why can we exchange numbers when working with modulo expressions?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Please excuse me if the answer is obvious because I'm a beginner.

Why can we exchange numbers when working with modulo expressions?

For example:

$$4^2 \equiv (-1)^2 \pmod{5}$$

You may say the replacement between $4$ and $-1$ is justified because:

$$4\equiv -1 \pmod{5}$$

I understand that equality, when you divide $4$ by $5$ you get a remainder $4$ and if we subtract $5$ from that we get $-1$. But I still don't understand why we can replace $4$ with $-1$.

Furthermore if $a\equiv c \pmod{b}$ are we justified in replacing $a$ with $c$ in every occasion?

Comment: Use \pmod{a} to generate $\pmod{a}$.

Comment: One proves a theorem, and then one uses it freely, usually without explicit mention. The general relevant theorem here is that if $a\equiv b\pmod{m}$ and $c\equiv \pmod{m}$ then $ac\equiv bd\pmod{m}$. The proof is not difficult. There is a similar theorem for addition. A consequence is that for any polynomial $P(x_1,\dots,x_n)$, if $b_i\equiv a_i\pmod{m}$ then $P(a_1,\dots,a_n)\equiv P(b_1,\dots,b_n)\pmod{m}$.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge and for editing my question @ZainPatel

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla: You are welcome. As I mentioned earlier, most of the time when we use these facts we don't mention why, just like when doing arithmetic one does not give step by step justification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need the function you are dealing with to preserve multiplication. In fancier language, that means it is a homomorphism from $(\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$ to $(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\cdot)$. In simpler language, that means that if $x,y$ are integers then $f(x \cdot y)=[x] \cdot [y]$, where the first $\cdot$ is integer multiplication, $[z]$ denotes the equivalence class of $z$ mod $n$, and the second $\cdot$ represents multiplication mod $n$. (Note that we often represent $[z]$ by the remainder of $z$ after division by $n$.)

For example $f : \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},f(x)=[x^2]$ is such a homomorphism, so $a^2 \equiv b^2 \mod n$ whenever $a \equiv b \mod n$. (Here $[y]$ denotes the equivalence class of $y$ mod $n$.) On the other hand, although $4 \equiv 9 \mod 5$, $2^4$ and $2^9$ are not equivalent mod 5.

Comment: Although I don't know what that means, and have tried to understand, I will probably understand in the future. Do you happen to know when is the term "homomorphism" taught? Furthermore, is every polynomial a "homomorphism"?

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla The word "homomorphism" is taught in abstract algebra. Its meaning is simple, let me edit.